# How can I tell if my drink is really sugar free?

Tags: restaurants, dietary-restrictions

I suffer from diabetes mellitus and when travelling, I always try to avoid sugar in food and drinks. I prefer home made food, and when at a new restaurant, I generally skip the dessert unless I'm sure it is sugar free.

With drinks anyway I have troubles sometimes. It happened to me a few times when travelling that I ordered a light coke/pepsi, etc. and was served normal coke instead.
From my experience this typically happens because the waiter *misses* the word "light", maybe because their english is not so good or because they are in a hurry, or don't have light coke at all but don't want to disappoint the customer, or simply because they don't care.
Coke with and without sugar have a similar taste but normal coke has a stronger aftertaste and sticks to the mouth and teeth more than light coke does. I can tell the difference, but only after taking a few sips of the drink.
Sometimes I also notice sugar in *sugar-free* warm drinks, like coffee and tea drinks, albeit less frequently. It's not that a few teaspoons of sugar would kill me, but this unclarity bothers me.

Is there a way I can tell if a drink contains sugar before actually drinking it?

Comment: This is not really about travelling.

Comment: Does "only drink water" count as an answer?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about travel. It's about reading labels. I guess there could be a question here about what countries have accurate labelling on products - would that even be on topic though?

Comment: there is no label on a glass or mug. And when travelling the language barrier or different prevalence of various medical problems could affect the chances of being served the wrong item in a restaurant

Comment: Ask for the drink in the can maybe.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for [Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: A related issue to "language barrier" is knowing what to ask for.  For instance, if you travel to the US and order "light Coke", the waiter's English will probably be just fine, but you still won't be understood: in the US, sugar-free Coca-Cola is sold as **Diet Coke** (or an alternative formulation, Coke Zero).

Comment: I voted to re-open as this is about traveling, as in your own country you can just ask and you know the way waiting staff handles requests. When traveling you meet (many) different cultures and languages.

Comment: I feel like this is too broad of a question - there are 200+ countries out there with wildly different availability of drink options.

Comment: I don't think the question is either too broad nor off-topic. The OP has no problem with locating sugar-free drinks at home, only when travelling. I feel there must be many diabetic travellers who might have this problem

Answer (score 9):

Here's a site showing various electronic devices and a manual solution (test strips) that seems to solve your problem: https://mysugr.com/diet-drink-really-diet-check-sugar/

100 test strips for $25 with the suggestion that you can cut them in half to last longer. That would probably last you a few trips and give you peace of mind.

Here's another (old) site recommending the use of test strips: http://home.ptd.net/~hwagner/2r_strip.htm typically used to test urine, but could also be used to test drinks for sugar content. Here's a random site selling such strips: https://www.enasco.com/product/SB09754M though it might be adisable to speak to your doctor to determine if these should be used for your purpose during your travels.